# Can't connect to Django on EC2 instance with nginx/gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am trying to browse to my Django site hosted on an EC2 instance with nginx/gunicorn. I have the correct port open(8000) and have bound the ip address(0:8000). I can navigate to the site using lynx in the terminal only when I am logged into the EC2 instance. I cannot browse to the site using the dns:port. Could this be a problem with virtualenv?

I ran ps -ef | grep nginx to make sure nginx was running and received this:

```
root      4860     1  0 17:36 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx     4862  4860  0 17:36 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process                   
ec2-user  4930  4529  0 17:44 pts/2    00:00:00 grep nginx
```

To further add to the confusion, I was able to connect to the site using an apache server a few days ago. However, I was not using virtualenv.

nginx.conf:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;
    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to the site via lynx on port 8000 when on the EC2, but can't get to it via a different browser across the internet, the problem is definitely *not* related to anything like "are you in a virtualenv".

Most candidate is that you don't actually have port 8000 unfirewalled, as you think you do.

What happens if you try telnet from a machine across the internet?

```
telnet yoursite.org 8000

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: yoursite.org
```

Can you connect at all? Does it hang? Do you get something back?

Comment: it simply hangs. navigating to the site via the browser on port 80 shows the nginx page indicating the server is set up correctly.

Comment: Oddly enough, I tried navigating to the site a few hours ago. After waiting for it to load for about 5 minutes, I simply got fed up and shut my laptop. I opened it a few hours later to find that the site had loaded, but I can't connect again

Comment: So it sounds like "gunicorn works fine" (i.e., you can connect to unicorn on port 8000 from the local box) and "nginx is running and reachable" (i.e., you can connect across the internet on port 80). And that there's some serious, weird delay between them.

Comment: Perhaps posting your gunicorn and nginx config files might show us something obviously weird.

Comment: added nginx.conf. I can navigate to my site via port 80 despite launching unicorn on port 8000

Comment: I'm not sure it's your problem, but one thing that strikes me as odd about your nginx is `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000`. Your server may resolve "0.0.0.0" as itself, but that's not universal. I'd make that `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

Comment: (you may have been confused because you run your gunicorn on 0.0.0.0:8000, meaning "make available on all of my interfaces on port 8000". But nginx needs to know what IP to connect to unicorn on)

Comment: I fixed that and it still won't connect. I don't understand why it would work on port 80 and not port 8000 when Im running unicorn on port 8000